# A PowerShell script like one-way rsync but worse

Tags: performance, file-system, powershell, network-file-transfer

This PowerShell script works a bit like a one-way `rsync`; it's good enough for my Surface RT needs, anyway. However, seeing as this is my first PS script, and I was learning the very basics while working on it, I suspect I may have committed many crimes of fashion and/or formatting. Also, it's much, *much* slower than the Python script it replaced (an average workload went from ~1 minute to ~8 minutes), and I can't figure out why; hints would be appreciated.

```
Param(
  [String]$LocalBase = "C:\Users\Michael\hddbackup",
  [String]$PortableBase = "C:\Users\Michael\hdd",
  [Switch]$WhatIf = $WhatIfPreference
)
$LocalBase = (Get-Item $LocalBase).FullName
$PortableBase = (Get-Item $PortableBase).FullName
$WhatIfPreference = $WhatIf

Function Select-Item (
  [Hashtable]$ChoiceList = (Throw "Choice list required"),
  [String]$Caption = "Please make a selection",
  [String]$Message = "",
  [int]$Default = 0
) {
  # I would use $Host.ui.PromptForChoice, but this has to run in
  #  ConstrainedLanguageMode (because Win RT), and you can't create
  #  System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription objects in
  #  that mode.
  If ($Message -ne "") {Write-Host $Message}
  $ChoiceList.Keys | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host ("  [" + $_ + "]") $ChoiceList[$_]
  }
  [String]$Answer = ""
  Do {
    $Answer = Read-Host $Caption
  } Until ($ChoiceList.Keys -contains $Answer)
  Return $Answer
}

Function Relative-Path (
  [String]$Path = (Throw "Path required"),
  [String]$BasePath = $pwd
) {
  Push-Location $BasePath
  Try {
    Return Resolve-Path -Relative -LiteralPath $Path
  } Finally {Pop-Location}
}

Function New-MockFile (
  [String]$Path,
  [Bool]$IsDir
) {
  # Oh, it's a pain making something that looks like a file but isn't
  [PSObject]$Mock = New-Object PSObject
  $ModeDirChar = $IsDir | Invoke-Command {If ($input) {'d'} Else {'-'}}
  $Mock | Add-Member @{"Name" = $Path.Substring($Path.LastIndexOf("\") + 1);
                       "FullName" = $Path;
                       "Length" = 0;
                       "LastWriteTime" = [DateTime]0;
                       "Mode" = $ModeDirChar + '----'}
  Return $Mock
}

Function Get-MaybeItem (
  [String]$Path,
  [Bool]$IsDirDefault
) {
  # Don't remove -LiteralPath unless you want anything with glob chars to blow up
  $item = Get-Item -LiteralPath $Path -ErrorAction Ignore
  If ($item) {Return $item} Else {Return New-MockFile $Path $IsDirDefault}
}

Function Get-FileSyncOptions (
  [Bool]$NewTarget
) {
  [Hashtable]$Opts = @{
    "S" = "Copy source over target";
    "T" = "Copy target over source";
    "1" = "Delete from target";
    "2" = "Delete from source";
    "X" = "Delete from source and target";
    "C" = "Skip";
    "A" = "Abort script"
  }
  If ($NewTarget) {
    # Have to manually override -WhatIf so things actually get removed from the table
    @("1", "T", "X") | ForEach-Object {$Opts.Remove($_)} -WhatIf:$false
    $Opts["S"] = "Create at target"
  }
  Return $Opts
}

Function Synchronise-File (
  [String]$FromPath = (Throw "FromPath required"),
  [String]$ToPath = (Throw "ToPath required"),
  [Bool]$IsDirectory = (Throw "IsDirectory required"),
  [String]$FromBase = (Throw "FromBase required"),
  [String]$ToBase = (Throw "ToBase required")
) {
  $From = (Get-MaybeItem $FromPath); $To = (Get-MaybeItem $ToPath)
  If ($From.LastWriteTime -eq $To.LastWriteTime) {Return}
  If ($IsDirectory -and -not ($To.LastWriteTime -eq [DateTime]0)) {Return}
  # just DST weirdness?
  If ($From.LastWriteTime - $To.LastWriteTime -eq [TimeSpan]"1:00:00") {
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $From.FullName -Destination $To.FullName
    Return
  } ElseIf ($To.LastWriteTime - $From.LastWriteTime -eq [TimeSpan]"1:00:00") {
    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $To.FullName -Destination $From.FullName
    Return
  }
  # different files, or a new directory
  Write-Host; Write-Host
  Write-Host (Relative-Path $From.FullName $FromBase).Substring(1)
  @($From, $To) | Format-Table @(
    @{Label="Location"; Expression={
        If ($_.FullName.Contains($FromBase + "\")) {"Source"} Else {"Target"}
      }},
    @{Label="Base"; Expression={
        If ($_.FullName.Contains($FromBase + "\")) {$FromBase} Else {$ToBase}
      }},
    @{Label="Modified"; Expression={$_.LastWriteTime}},
    @{Label="Size"; Expression={$_.Length}}
  ) -AutoSize -Wrap
  Switch (Select-Item -Caption "Select file action" `
                      (Get-FileSyncOptions ($To.LastWriteTime -eq [DateTime]0))) {
    "S" {Copy-Item -LiteralPath $From.FullName -Destination $To.FullName}
    "T" {Copy-Item -LiteralPath $To.FullName -Destination $From.FullName}
    "1" {Remove-Item -LiteralPath $To.FullName -Recurse -Force}
    "2" {Remove-Item -LiteralPath $From.FullName -Recurse -Force}
    "X" {Remove-Item -LiteralPath @($From.FullName, $To.FullName) -Recurse -Force -Confirm}
    "C" {}
    "A" {Exit}
  }
}

Function Test-Directory (
  [String]$Path,
  [Bool]$IsDirDefault
) {
  Try {
    Return (Get-MaybeItem $Path $IsDirDefault).Mode[0] -eq "d"
  } Catch {Return $false}
}

# Thanks to <http://vwiki.co.uk/Files_and_Folders_(PowerShell)>
Function Synchronise-FileTree (
  [String]$FromPath = (Throw "FromPath required"),
  [String]$ToPath = (Throw "ToPath required"),
  [String]$FromBase = $FromPath,
  [String]$ToBase = $ToPath
) {
  If (!(Test-Path $FromPath)) {Return}
  If (!(Test-Path $ToPath)) {Return}
  Get-ChildItem $FromPath | ForEach-Object {
    # http://stackoverflow.com/q/12396025/1053021
    $From = $_
    $To = Get-MaybeItem ($ToBase + "\" + (Relative-Path $_.FullName $FromBase))
    If (Test-Directory $From.FullName) {
      If (!(Test-Directory $To.FullName $true)) {Throw "Directory/file mismatch"}
      Synchronise-File $From.FullName $To.FullName $true $FromBase $ToBase
      # now recurse!
      Synchronise-FileTree $From.FullName $To.FullName $FromBase $ToBase
    } Else {
      If (Test-Directory $To.FullName $false) {Throw "File/directory mismatch"}
      Synchronise-File $From.FullName $To.FullName $false $FromBase $ToBase
      # no recursion needed
    }
  }
}

Switch (Select-Item -Caption "Select synchronisation direction" `
                    @{"T" = "To portable";
                      "F" = "From portable";
                      "C" = "Cancel"}) {
  "T" {Synchronise-FileTree $LocalBase $PortableBase}
  "F" {Synchronise-FileTree $PortableBase $LocalBase}
  "C" {}
}
```

Additional notes:

- This **must** work on Windows RT machines, so anything that doesn't work in [`ConstrainedLanguageMode`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn433292.aspx) is out of the question. (Yes, I'd love to use `$Host.ui.PromptForChoice`...)
- I'm told that `(Throw "parameter required")` is a fairly idiomatic way of making a parameter required without lots of messing about with obscure attributes; correct me if I'm wrong here.
- I'm not really a fan of aliases; forgive me for using full cmdlet names.

Comment: Also, goodness me this syntax highlighter needs work.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't gone through your code in detail, but what I've seen looks fine.

I notice you use initial caps for the keywords (e.g. `If` rather than `if`, `Else` rather than `else`). That doesn't really matter, but it's non-standard, and it makes your code look a bit like Visual Basic (and we don't want that now do we? :). Plus it's less efficient to type since you have to hit the shift key all the time.

On a side note, you might be better off using Robocopy or SyncToy or something rather than rolling your own solution.

Comment: On capitalisation: PowerShell seems confused as to what "standard" is. [The `ForEach` loop's TechNet page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847816.aspx) says `ForEach`, the page contents say `Foreach`, the sample code says `foreach` (or `ForEach`, depending on which you look at)... oh, and the cmdlet that does the same job is `ForEach-Object` (or maybe `Foreach-Object`), just to add to the case confusion. (I'm surprised there was no occurence of `forEach` in there.) What's a coder to do but pick one and stick with it?

Comment: @michaelb958, I would go by the sample code. In any case, I was talking about keywords such as `if`, `else`, `function`, etc., not cmdlets. I've only ever seen them in all lowercase.

Comment: @michaelb958 for aliases of cmdlets, such as `foreach`, `select` etc., they are defined to be lowercase. Execute `alias` at the command line to see them.

Comment: Also, this has to run on a Surface RT and a Windows 7 PC, which makes it a bit harder to find an off-the-shelf solution - apps don't work on the PC, executables fail on the Surface...

Comment: @michaelb958, I think robocopy may come with RT. I don't know if MS makes SyncToy for RT or not.